# Encode to UTF-8. Encode character eg. ö to Ã¶

Tags: java, android, encoding, utf-8, urlencode

I want to encode a string in Android to UTF-8. For example this string:

```
Grüne Ähren beißen Flöhe
```

to

```
GrÃ¼ne Ãhren beiÃen FlÃ¶he
```

But no matter what I do I encode ü to ü or ü to %C3%BC (online often called 'raw URL encode').

Found solutions to convert to byte[] or URI.toASCIIString(). But non of them work for me.

**UPDATE**

I am participating in the eBay partner network and try to concat a searchword to my partner url. 
The people of eBay must use a wrong character set, as UTF-8 URL encoded string don't work.

A searchword with UTF-8 URL encoding

(Grüne Ähren beißen Flöhe

to

Gr%C3%BCne%20%C3%84hren%20bei%C3%9Fen%20Fl%C3%B6he)

comes out to this result in the eBay searchbox:

[image: Wrong encoding in eBay searchbox]

If I encode my searchword with ISO_8859_1 it works (GrÃ¼ne Ãhren beiÃen FlÃ¶he):

[image: Right encoding in eBay searchbox]

**Thank you very much community**

Comment: You need to understand that encoding `Grüne Ähren beißen Flöhe` to utf-8 will still be `Grüne Ähren beißen Flöhe`. Supposedly the underlying bytes will be different, that is, if the text in question is stored as text bytes.

Comment: I don't think you understand what happens here. UTF-8 has its own way of encoding characters to bytes. An `ö` is still an `ö` if you transform it to its 2-byte-representation (C3 B6) using UTF8 and _also use UTF8_ to transform it back to a character. You get your desired `Ã¶` if you transform it to UTF8-bytes but transform it back using ISO-8859-1, which is usually what your would _not_ want.

Comment: Thanks @kumesana for your comment. Makes total sense. I was mislead by the online converters telling me this encoding was UTF-8 (eg. [link](https://encoder.mattiasgeniar.be). But the question remains. How to convert the Umlauts etc. to these cryptic characters?

Comment: What @f1sh already mentioned is that you usually don't want that to happen. May I ask what you intend to do? Simulate text data read with wrong encoding?

Comment: It sounds like you've encountered a terminal (most likely on Windows) that is configured with the wrong character set and when UTF-8 was printed you saw an incorrect representation of special characters. The solution is to configure the terminal correctly.

Comment: "How to convert the Umlauts etc. to these cryptic characters?" -> `byte[] utfBytes = text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8); String wrangledText = new String(utfBytes, "windows-1252");` Beware that some (many) texts will be corrupted when attempting to do that.

Comment: @mumpitz I updated my question to satisfy your interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you essentially want is to convert a String to it's byte representation according to `UTF-8` and interpret these bytes using a different Charset, such as `ISO-8859-1`.

This is usually the cause of many problems. You want to intentionally do what most developers do incorrectly (or they simply ignore the problems of charsets).

Since you just need this to work, use this piece of code:

```
byte[] bytes = "Grüne Ähren beißen Flöhe".getBytes("UTF-8");
String result = new String(bytes, "ISO-8859-1");
```

see it at work [here](https://ideone.com/mz0D5h).

Comment: Of course the result is garbage. And relies on the ISO-8891-1 to represent the special chars, that would be different in say ISO-8891-13.

Comment: @JoopEggen technically, OP literally asked how to obtain that thing which is garbage.

Comment: @kumesana yes, I did not mean to criticize, just once again the result is not useful, other than see whether errors in reading UTF-8 stems from reading by ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @f1sh Thank you very much for clarification on my question.

Comment: _Encoding_ bytes to characters is a thing. Base64 is a very common way of doing it. It is also easily documented. Unfortunately, some use the reverse of the ISO 8859-1 encoding for the same purpose. I call it Base256 encoding. The big problem with it is that it is often confused with plain text or seen as mojibake and it is hardly ever documented for what it is.